# Get the table details from a URL

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I just want to get the table details from the HTML and for example the URL is,

```
$url="https://www.centralbank.org.bz/rates-statistics/exchange-rates";
```

From this,I need to get the `currency rate` table in this `url` and also remove all the `dirty data`.

Please help me,
Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any code work that you may have done.

Comment: please show your html code. So, its easy to identify more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ::

> ```
> $url = 'https://www.centralbank.org.bz/rates-statistics/exchange-rates';
> $content = file_get_contents($url);
> $first_step = explode( '<table id="currencyTable">' , $content );
> $second_step = explode("</table>" , $first_step[1] );
>
> echo $second_step[0];
> ```

Comment: not getting the output

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/),

An example may be helpful to you:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=543171';

$html = file_get_html($url);
$links = array();
foreach($html->find('a[class="postlink"]') as $a) {
 $links[] = $a->href;
}

print_r($links);

?>
```

Comment: Since the data isn't in the raw HTML, that won't be enough.

Comment: @Quentin can you please help me out to solve this

Comment: @ShebeerAhammed — See the duplicate question.